# Jquery hide show specific div element on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am struggling a bit with this, I can hide/show/fadin/fadout all day long but I am trying to get my head round the logic of targetting an element in my  and pulling its specific description on mouseover, I have come close to getting this but feel like im missing something, below is my HTML:

```
<ul id="menu" class="menu">
                        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                        <li id="menu1" class="menu-link"><a href="/">LINK1</a></li>
                        <li id="menu2" class="menu-link"><a href="/">LINK2</a></li>
                        <li id="menu3" class="menu-link"><a href="/">LINK3</a></li>
                        <li id="menu4" class="menu-link"><a href="/">LINK4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="menu1content" class="menuDescription">
                        Description for "menu1"
                    </div>
                    <div id="menu2content" class="menuDescription">
                        Description for "menu2"
                    </div>
                    <div id="menu3content" class="menuDescription">
                        Description for "menu3"
                    </div>
                    <div id="menu4content" class="menuDescription">
                        Description for "menu4"
                    </div>
```

and here is my CSS, the idea is to position the description just above its corresponding

element btw:

```
.menu{
    font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular';
    position: absolute;
    top:25px;
    overflow:hidden;
    right:100px;
    float:right;

}
.menu ul{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.menu li{
    display:inline;
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.menu li a{
    float:left;
    width:6em;
}

.menuDescription  {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    position: absolute;
    right: 407px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    top: 15px;
}
```

and finally here is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.menuDescription').hide();
    $('li.menu-link').bind('mouseover', function() {
        $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'content').prependTo("li.menu-link").fadeIn();
    })

            .mouseout(function() {
                $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'content').fadeOut();
            });

});
```

Comment: you have uppercase IDs `MENU1` & lowercase `menu1content` ids

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: I have amended and apologies, just had to sign up to jsfiddle, here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/dyates88/5BF7F/

Comment: Do you have to use JS? There is a purely CSS solution for this. Do you have some idea about where you want the description to appear? If you are planning to build menus with submenus, you'll need to restructure your HTML a bit. Also, could you plz require your version of jquery in the fiddle?

Comment: hi, yeah I know there is a way of doing it in css, i was just looking for a more supported method, i am calling jquery by <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> in my header

Comment: What is your targeted support spectrum? I have added an answer which works in Chrome, FF and IE7+. I couldn't test on Safari just now but have used this before on a major project.

Answer (score 1):

WHen you have a one-to-one relationship between 2 sets of elements and their order in each set matches, is generally easier to use indexing rather than parsing ID

```
var $content= $('div.menuDescription');
var $links=$('.menu-link').hover(function(){
   /* "this" is element being hovered*/
   var index= $links.index(this);
   $content.stop().hide().eq(index).fadeIn(); 
},function(){
   /* not sure if you want to leave current content visible if user leaves menu, if so do nothing here*/
})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BCULt/)**</kbd>

Comment: hi, I have tried your example over and over but I cannot get it to work, I need the content to initially be hidden , appear on mouseover and disappear on mouseout. If i take off position:absolute from my menudescription the div hides completely and nothing happens on rollover

Comment: like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/BCULt/2/ I changed to hover on `<a>`. depends how CSS set up for best setup

Comment: i have copied you exact code from the jsfiddle and it is still not working, now it is showing the li borders as several lines to the right of the menu :s

Comment: create demo in jsfiddle that replicates problem. May need to modify depending on your css

Comment: i have added you jquery to my jsfiddle and it is still not working, btw the css is the same as i have on my actual webpage.. http://jsfiddle.net/dyates88/5BF7F/

Comment: prepend selector will prepend to all `'menu_link` if you want it there, why not set html up so content is already in the LI's?

Comment: @charlietfl, I have already posted a solution which has moved the content within the LIs.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated and simplified your fiddle to make it work: [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BF7F/5/). Here is the simplified code without any JS:

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu" class="menu">
  <li>
      <a href="">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu1" class="menu-link">
      <a href="/">LINK1</a>
      <div id="menu1content" class="menuDescription">
        Description for "menu1"
      </div>
  </li>
  <li id="menu2" class="menu-link">
      <a href="/">LINK2</a>
      <div id="menu2content" class="menuDescription">
         Description for "menu2"
      </div>
  </li>
  <li id="menu3" class="menu-link">
      <a href="/">LINK3</a>
      <div id="menu3content" class="menuDescription">
         Description for "menu3"
      </div>
    </li>
  <li id="menu4" class="menu-link">
      <a href="/">LINK4</a>
      <div id="menu4content" class="menuDescription">
         Description for "menu4"
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.menu{
    font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular';
    position: absolute;
    top:25px;
    overflow:hidden;
    right:100px;
    float:right;

}
.menu ul{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.menu li{
    float:left;
    margin: 0 5px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
}
.menu li a{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.menu li .menuDescription {
    display: none;
}

.menu li:hover .menuDescription {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 120px;
}

.menuDescription  {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Let me know if you need any explanations and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: hi, i have added your code to my webpage yet all the description divs are simply shown a little further down the page, they aren't hidden and nothign occurs on rollover

Comment: 1. Is your web page public? 2. When copying this code, did you update the HTML to remove the description divs outside the <ul>? They'll get pushed down a little if they are not removed. 3. Finally, you need to get rid of the original JS which you had. The JS will interfere with the working of this code.

Comment: 1. unfortunately, no. 2. yes and 3. i have removed the js

Comment: Is it working for you in the fiddle or is it not working for you even there? Also, on your webpage, do you have other CSS and HTML? Try creating a page with just this HTML and CSS and then add your elements one by one. You'll be able to nail down the problematic component.

Comment: See this solution working live [here](http://www.saholic.com/). The top level menu of this site has a secondary menu attached with each menu item. Hovering over the top level menu items would open the secondary menu.